# How to reduce the impact of gravity on a single SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I am building an endless runner game where platforms appear at random intervals and then scroll right to left across the screen.

I have a sprite that jumps up vertically using

```
- (void)makeCharacterJump {

[self.spriteCaveman.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0.0f, 80.0f)];

}
```

The problem is that the effect of gravity on the sprite means that it falls quite quickly and cant make the gap between the platforms.

What I would like to do is slightly slow down the effect of gravity on the falling sprite so it creates the impression of slightly floating down.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your caveman the only node affected by gravity ?

Comment: Yes, it will be the only node I think that is effected by gravity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the character is the only node affected by gravity then you can change the scene’s gravity with:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, desiredGravity);
```

If it is not then you’ll have to play with the character’s physics body properties: friction, linearDamping or angularDamping values.

Hope that helps.